# $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \csc{\theta}} f(r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) r dr d\theta$ is wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$I=\int_0^{\sqrt2/2}\int_y^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$
I want to put this is polar coordinate. Here is my answer:
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sqrt2/2\csc\theta}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)r\,dr\,d\theta$$
Why am I wrong here?

Comment: Can you please provide some details of your work? How did you go from cartesian coordinates to polar? It is more important for you to write what you understand of the region than just writing the bounds

Comment: Also try and sketch the region before you convert. You will see your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the original region reveals it to be merely a circular sector with radius $1$ bounded by $\theta=0,\pi/4$, so the correct bounds are
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^1(\dots)\,dr\,d\theta$$

Comment: Can you explain how you get  r between 0 and 1?